# I want to feature a grouped product, but it shows a price of $0.00. Can I show minimum price?

Tags: grouped-products, group, group-price

I want to feature a grouped product, but it shows a price of $0.00.  Can I show minimum price? Or better yet, can I show "starting at $xx.xx?"

Comment: can you post some screenshots of your products configuration? At least the price and products tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your products priced at $0.00? A Grouped Product type gets it "Starting at" value from the least cost of the min qty of one of the associated products (at least in 1.9.1).

You should make sure that all associated products have a price > $0.00 and that you're truly using a Group Product type. Don't confuse this with a Bundle where it is possible to have a Starting At $0.00 if the core price is set at $0.00.